# "Ordinal Not Found" when running the Diesel CLI tool

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-diesel

I tried to install `diesel_cli` and after some environment variable issues I installed it successfully.

When I tried to setup Diesel for my project, it throws an error:

> diesel.exe - Ordinal Not Found
>
> The ordinal 4701 could not be located in the dynamic link library "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\lib\LIBPQ.dll."

[image: error message dialog]

Comment: *after some environment variable issues* — you most likely still have these issues. For example, do you have multiple versions of Postgres installed? Be sure that you've configured whatever environment you are running `diesel.exe` in to be the same as the environment in which you built it.

Comment: Actually the problem was with the postgres version and not with the environment variables it seems, which has been resolved. Thanks a lot for your response @Shepmaster. Please accept the answer if you think it would help someone in future.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the issue was the postgreSQL version.
AFAIK, Postgres 11 is not compatible for diesel setup. Even if i had libpq.dll in lib folder of my postgres/11/lib folder structure. It throws the "pictured" error in the question.

Then, i tried uninstalling the postgres version 11.1 and installed the Postgres 10.6 version it works smoothly.

**Note: After postgres install dn't forget to set environment variables**

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same error.

When I dug into it I found that I had a incompatible version of `ssleay32.dll` on my system path as part of the Intel Wifi drivers.

In my case this was in `C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS`. Removing this from my system path fixed the issue.