# Rust compiling error: process didn't exit successfully

Tags: compiler-errors, rust, rust-cargo, rust-diesel

Recently, I have not been able to do `cargo run` in Rust. The error I get is
`error: process didn't exit successfully: target\debug\backend.exe (exit code: 0xc0000138, STATUS_ORDINAL_NOT_FOUND)`

It happens after the compiler seems to finish saying
`Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 2m 43s
     Running target\debug\backend.exe`

I have tried running `cargo clean` and the running `cargo run`, but I get the same error. `cargo fix` doesn't seem to help either.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are experiencing the same thing as ["Ordinal Not Found" when running the Diesel CLI tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53456457/ordinal-not-found-when-running-the-diesel-cli-tool). It seems like there's some kind of version conflict with the Intel drivers.

Comment: Yea, after testing it does seem that way which prevents the server from connecting with PostGres. The safest way to get around it unfortunately seems to be to paste the PostGres pathway in the terminal, as environmental variables only work if I delete the `ssleay32.dll` file mentioned in that post. Hoping eventually there will be a better solution.